# 401 Unauthorized Error On GET Request, Is It CORS Problem

Tags: javascript, request, cors

I am having 401 Unauthorized error when sending get request. I am confused because I can send request over the terminal with curl or postman but not from the code (localhost)

## CODE

```
   const carId = '2F3A228F6F66AEA580'
    var query = 'https://api.mercedes-benz.com/experimental/connectedvehicle/v1/vehicles/'.concat(carId).concat('/doors')

    console.log(query)
    console.log(this.state.access_token)

    var bearer = 'Bearer ' + this.state.access_token

    console.log(bearer)
    const response = await fetch(query, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'authorization': bearer
      },
    })
```

Note : I am using the same access_token

Comment: In code you are using `Bearer` scheme but in postman you are not.... id imagine that has something to do with it. Also you should set up middleware to allow different origins.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image.

Comment: I didnt use image to post my codes @hindmost

Comment: @Berkin Yes, you did. CURL command could be posted as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am having 401 Unauthorized error when sending get request.

No, you aren't. Read the error message more carefully.

It says that you are making an `OPTIONS` request, not a `GET` request.

The browser is making a [preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) because you are trying to make a cross-origin request with an `authorization` header.

The server appears to be testing for authorization for the OPTIONS request. This fails because the browser has not been given permission to send a cross-origin Ajax request with credentials.